# Can i use activities for all my layouts for any application?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android application development.
If i am using n number of layouts in my project and i need to change layouts with the user interaction.
Should i use different activities for different layouts or can i use setContentView to switch layouts.
Which one will be effecient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Fragment instead of new activities.
[Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) can be used for adding fragments to Android Version 4 and above.
Each Layout can be a separate Fragment and is loaded into FragmentContainer ( a ViewGroup defined in main layout file) based in user actions